# Splitting string in python when last part may not exist

Tags: python

How do I split the foll. in python:

```
'a_b_c'
```

The appraoch should also work if string is `'a_b'`

Comment: `if len('a_b_c'.split('a_b')) > 1 :`

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Comment: Why is this question down voted?

Comment: Why down vote (i don't care any one) and don't edit question ?

Comment: @pylang the question is downvoted because it doesn't specify: 1) what the OP has already tried? 2) what is the expected output after splitting?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, although I think the expected outcome can be inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
splited = "a_b_c".split('_')
```

`inputstring.split('_')` will split it.

Comment: Dear downvotters, Leave a comment, I hope that will help me to learn more

Comment: Agreed.  What do you mean by `str.split('-')` will split it?  Where do you get `str`?

Comment: I don't think you need that line.  It's clear `split()` is a string method.

Comment: @AKS, My bad. Now i corected it.  put - instead of _

Comment: @pylang, But stock overflow does't let em add the answr. I typed only splited = "a_b_c".split('_'). But it did not allow me to post it. So i added the general format

Comment: This is sufficient `"a_b_c".split('_')` (since "splited" isn't a word anyhow), but it still doesn't address the second part of his question, regarding `"a_b"`

Comment: @AKS, I think you can remove the downvote in my answer. Since i have corrected it

Comment: @pylang, I assume that. The OP wants a general methoed to split the stirng. no matter how many _ is present in the string.

Comment: @Backtrack: I would if I could. But I didn't downvote you ;).

Comment: Don't forget to add backticks to `inputstring.split('_')`